# Python XML Parse Attribute not available

Tags: python, pandas, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse the below block of the xml message:
''''

```
<Recommendations>
    <STOpinion>
        <ConsOpinion code="1" set="STD" desc="By">
            <ConsOpValue type="NumOfEst" unit="N">
                <ConsValue dateType="CURR">15</ConsValue>
            </ConsOpValue>
        </ConsOpinion>
    </STOpinion>
</Recommendations>
```

''''

With this as my code:
''''

```
opin_type=[]
opin_count=[]



        

for i in d.iter('Recommendations'):
                i_iter=et.Element('root')
                i_iter=i
                for j in i.iter('STOpinion'):
                    j_iter=et.Element('root')
                    j_iter=j
                    for k in j.iter('ConsOpinion'):
                        k_iter=et.Element('root')
                        k_iter=k
                        for l in k.iter('ConsOpValue'):
                            l_iter=et.Element('root')
                            l_iter=l
                            for m in l.iter('ConsValue'):
                                m_iter=et.Element('root')
                                m_iter=m
                                opin_type.append(k.attrib['desc'])
                                opin_count.append(m.text)
```

''''
However I am not able to get the value for k.attrib['desc'], it only shows {set:"STD"} as an attribute. I need to pull the value for k.attrib['desc']- is there another way to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify: is your expected output `By` or something else?

Comment: Yup my expected outcome is 'By'

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with xml, you might as well use an xml parser to extract values:

```
recs = """your xml above"""

from lxml import etree
doc = etree.fromstring(recs)
print(doc.xpath('//STOpinion//ConsOpinion/@desc')[0])
```

Output:

```
By
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, This works on the string but I am not able to apply it to my xml msg. It is not able to find that index as it does not recognize @desc.  I validated the format of the message so can't think of what else it could be.

Comment: @Ksh Not sure what the problem is; it definitely works on the xml in your question. Maybe your actual xml is encoded/formatted differently.